# php artisan migrate is not working and showing no error

Tags: laravel-5.4, php-7.1

When I execute `php artisan migrate:refresh` it shown nothing. No error message no log in Laravel logs even waiting for a long time(half an our).

Then I restart mysql `sudo service mysql restart`. Then run the `migrate:refresh` command again and it worked. I though the issue was fixed so to check I run the same command again and the situation is same again. Nothing is being shown, no error, no logs.

I have no idea what going on. Don't know where I can find some information about the reason behind this situation.

Comment: someone please answer this

Comment: Hi, I cannot remember the exact solution. But one of colleague had this issue be cause he was running this command from his host machine instead of vagrant where the Laravel project was hosted.

Comment: its okay we got it solved.

Comment: @ichimaru how you solved your problem , help us

Comment: @Thom I forgot...